# Contribution to rollover IRA in 2020

Tags: united-states, ira, contribution, rollover

I am retired and rolled over my 401(k). My husband has earned income for 2020. And he has retirement plan in his work. We already contributed $7000 each to Roth IRA.

Can I contribute another $7000 to rollover ira for 2020?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $7,000 limit is across both flavors of IRA. Since you’ve deposited $7,000 already, you’re done. You should look to see what your 2021 plans are, and deposit for 2021 if you wish.